# Variables from properties.file not being passed - TestNG - WebDriver Test

Tags: java, testng

I am using Webdriver + TestNG.  I created a class where you can run any test with the browser of your choice just by using the method below where you enter which browser to run and what test to run as your variables. Now I am trying to feed my "browser" variable and "test" variable from a properties file.  When I run it I just get a Pass but nothing happens.  If I manually enter the variables it works fine. How come it wont take the values from the properties file?  If I do a print - it prints the correct value...

This is the contents of the properties file:

browser="BROWSER GOES HERE"

test="TEST GOES HERE"

Here is my method to run the test:

```
@Test
        public void runTest() throws IOException {
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(new FileInputStream(
                    "path\\test.properties"));
            localBrowser(prop.getProperty("browser"));
            masterTest(driver, prop.getProperty("test"));
        }
```

---

Here is a sandbox example of my test:

If I put the variables in myself the browser will open and execute the test.  If I use the property loader it will just print the variables but will not run the test. Here is a sandbox example so you can try it.

Package Structure:

-src/test/java
--SandboxTest
-src/test/resources
--test.properties

Properties File example:

browser=firefox
test=test1

Class example:

public class SandboxTest {

```
private WebDriver driver;
InputStream input = null;
Properties prop = new Properties();

@Test
public void runTest() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        input = new FileInputStream(
                (new File(
                    "C:INSERT_PATH_HERE\\test.properties")));
        prop.load(input);
            //This doesnt run the test
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("browser"));
        System.out.println(prop.getProperty("test"));
        localBrowser(prop.getProperty("browser"));
        masterTest(driver, prop.getProperty("test"));
        /* 
         * This works
                 * localBrowser("firefox");
         * masterTest(driver, "test1");
         */


}

public void localBrowser(String browser) {
    if (browser == "firefox") {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    } else if (browser == "chrome") {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                "C:\\INSERT_PATH_HERE\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    } else if (browser == "ie") {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver",
                "C:\\INSERT_PATH_HERE\\IEDriverServer.exe");
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
    }
}

public void masterTest(WebDriver driver, String test) {
    if (test == "test1") {
        Test1(driver);
    } else if (test == "test2") {
        Test2(driver);
    }
}

// *********************************TESTS*****************************************************

public void Test1(WebDriver driver) {
    driver.get("http://www.marca.com/en/");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Barcelona")).click();
}

public void Test2(WebDriver driver) {
    driver.get("http://www.marca.com");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Fútbol")).click();
}
```

}

Comment: You are saying that if you print this prop.getProperty("browser") It print the value but it won't be passed to function??

Comment: Correct @Aviad. If I set the browser property to firefox (browser=firefox) and do System.out.println(prop.getProperty("browser")); I will get firefox but when I do localBrowser(prop.getProperty("browser")); I get nothing.  If I pass the browser in the method like this it works  localBrowser("firefox").

Comment: If i understand correctly you can set browser=firefox in the properties file and it works.. So i didn't understood because you are still having a problem :) Can you show me the structure of your project also, the file is loaded properly?

Comment: @Aviad what I am saying is that it doesnt work passing it as a variable but I see the variable from the properties file if I do a sysout.  does that make sense?

Comment: @seleniumRookie - there cannot be a difference in behavior when you do System.out.println(prop.getProperty("SDf")) or when you do localBrowser(prop.getProperty("SDf")).  The problem seems to be somewhere else.  Put in code for localBrowser.  Print the value of browser in localBrowser as well as before making a call and share the output as well

Comment: @niharika_neo I agree with you that is why I am asking for help.  It is not making any sense to me as why it does not work if I know the method is picking up the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. I am really not sure what you are doing, But if it doesn't work so probably it doesn't load the properties file properly.

try this one

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/environment.properties");
properties = PropertiesLoaderUtils.loadProperties(resource);
```

Tell me if that is ok, hope that helps

EDIT:

The above is part of Spring,
you can use

```
prop.load(new FileInputStream(new File("test.properties")));
```

- Please make sure that test.properties will be under src folder in the project

EDIT:

The problem not in the property file.. The problem is in the way you are comparing 2 strings

When you do `browser == "firefox"` The check is for the object address(referenec)
When you are comparing Object type you need to use Eqauls
For example `browser.equals("firefox")` It will work this way.

Because when you put the value your self it check the refernece and it is the same.. Once you get from property this is 2 diffrent objects but they are "equal" So it will work only with Equals

Comment: ClassPathResource seems to be a spring framework method...Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, Not relevant? You can use another method.. I edit my answer

Comment: Still the same. If I do sysout I see the variables in the console but they still arent passed to the method.

Comment: Please edit your question with additional examples.. Show the project hirerchy and show where test.proprties file. In addition create example and show what it prints.. Just one main with print+ calling localBrowser method, And if you can add the implemenation of this method

Comment: I have added a "Sandbox" example you can take a look at.

Comment: I have update my answer.. The problem is with oprator == and equals.
You can read this in addition..http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/
Switch to equals and it will work for you

Answer (score 1):

What you should do instead is put [the property in the testing.xml](https://github.com/djangofan/simple-selenium-builder-framework/blob/master/src/test/resources/testng.xml) file and then read the property from there instead.   Then, if you need to have different property files, you can just create multiple testing.xml files and when you execute the tests just pass the testng.xml file as an argument to TestNG.

In the project I referenced above in the hyperlink, you can see I reference the properties something like so:

```
@BeforeClass
public void setUp( ITestContext context ) {
    suiteParams = context.getSuite().getXmlSuite().getAllParameters();
    String browser = suiteParams.get( "browser" );
    String sauceUser = suiteParams.get( "sauceUser" );
    String sauceKey = suiteParams.get( "sauceKey" )
  ....
```

If you have to do it using a properties file, then I would change you code and do it differently.  Something like so (assuming use of TestNG):

```
protected WebDriver driver;
protected String browser;
@BeforeTest
public void setUp() {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load( new FileInputStream("path/test.properties") );
    browser = prop.getProperty("browser");
    if ( browser.equals("firefox") {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }  else {
        driver = null; // bad choice
    }
}
@Test
public void runTest() throws IOException {
    driver.navigateTo( url);
    // do stuff
    Assert.assertTrue( 1 == 1 );
}
@AfterTest
public void cleanUp() {
    driver.quit();
}
```

Comment: The properties file is generated elsewhere that is why it has to be a properties file.

Comment: This is interesting but I need to stay away from the XML because after this project I will no longer be using TestNG.  I will be converting from Java to C# and will be using Nunit which I dont believe has the XML functionality.

Comment: If you switch to NUnit, then the second half of my answer still applies.  You need to use and be aware of the @Before phases of the unit test, which for NUnit is called "SetUp fixture" I think.  Personally I wouldn't consider changing to NUnit since TestNG is far superior for running parallel multi-threaded tests.

Comment: Unfortunately TestNG is only for Java so when I switch to C# I have no choice but to stop using TestNG.

Comment: if you assign the testng.xml parameters in the @BeforeClass method "setup"- correct me if i'm wrong but they will not be available outside of this method's scope.

Comment: @Dror - With JUnit 4.x, your right, but with TestNG, you do have access in BeforeMethod to any parameters being passed into the test method.  In other words, instance variables passed in can be modified during setup before the test starts.  For example, you could pass a WebDriver factory instance and a Capabilities object from your data provider into the test method and then  do operations on the capabilities object before starting the driver in BeforeTest.   Its all just hocus-pocus on how you setup your object oriented test design.   I've never used NUnit: does it have similar capability?

Comment: @djangofan I wouldn't know. I only use TestNG :) (recent starter). 
Just to make sure I understood correctly, you're saying :access in the "BeforeMethod to any parameters being passed into the test method"- is embedded in TestNG without any custom coding, and is considered good practice for test writing  ?

Comment: @Dror - see TestNG documentation, section 5.18.1  .  The documentation is a little vague, and most people don't realize you can do it.